# Github on multiple computers

Tags: github

I just started using github more seriously, and have a question,

most of the time I am working from my laptop however sometimes I work from my mac,

if I download the the git desktop app on the mac and clone the repo will I still have full access and if i update something will it update on laptop

thanks

Comment: Hi! If you're new to git and need to learn the basics like this, I suggest having a look online for some "introduction to git" and "git workflow" tutorials. There are lots out there - Github has some of their own, but you can find lots of others if those don't suit your learning style.

Answer (score 0):

You'll still have full access, but you'll need to do a git pull after you commit on one machine in order to sync with the work you've done on the other. It won't be automatic.